# client side locking required in Collections.synchronizedList

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

While writing putIfAbsent method for Collections.synchronizedList its required to provide explicit locking during accessing the list.

Following code snippet explains it in more detail:

```
class ListHelper <E> {
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employeeList.add(new Employee());
    //.. add more eomployees like this to the list
    public List<E> list = Collections.synchronizedList(employeeList);

    public boolean putIfAbsent(Employee x) {
                   boolean absent = !employeeList.contains(x);
            if (absent)
               employeeList.add(x);
            return absent;
           }
}
```

Please explain why is synchronized(employeeList) required inside put-if-absent method when we have Collections.synchronizedList which has a lock on the ArrayList object.

Thanks

Comment: Is `list` a field? What is `employeeList` in `list`'s initialization expression?

Comment: employeeList is simple array list which is having Employee Object values

Comment: Can you post a complete example? I feel like some context is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see an implementation of such a method:

```
public boolean putIfAbsent(Employee emp, List employeeList) {
    if (!employeeList.contains(emp)) {
        employeeList.add(emp);
    }
}
```

Such an implementation is thread-safe in the sense that even if multiple threads call it concurrently, the internal structure of the list won't be compromised, and the list will stay functional.

But it's not thread safe because there might be a race condition causing two threads to add the same element to the list twice:

```
T1: check if the employee is contained in the list: no
T2: check if the employee is contained in the list: no
T1: add the employee to the list
T2: add the employee to the list
```

And your `putIfAbsent()` method thus has a bug. That's why synchronization is needed.

Comment: But Collections.synchronizedXX  is already returning synchronized list then whats the need for extra synchronization

Comment: Well, have you read my answer? It explains it. The fact the the list is synchronized doesn't prevent thread T2 to call  `contains()` after T1 has called `contains()` and before it calls `add()`.

Comment: So it implies that inside Collections.synchronizedList add operation is synchronized ( thread-safe) but contains is not thread safe

Comment: No. Read my answer and my comment again. contains() is thread-safe. Nobody can call any method of the list while T1 executes contains(), because contains() ,is synchronized. Nobody can call any method of the list while T1 executes add(), because add() ,is synchronized. BUT, between the call to contains() and the call to add(), T1 is not executing any method on the list. So any other thread can execute contains().